# Extract details of SSL certificates using JavaScript/OpenSSL

Tags: javascript, ssl, firefox-addon, openssl

I am building a Firefox add-on that needs to extract details of SSL certificates received, like name of the [CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority), country of the CA (certificate authority). I want to know if it's possible to extract the above details using JavaScript or do I need to use [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) and thereby link both of them?

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Received how? Web page loaded into the browser, XMLHttpRequest, something else?

Comment: Wladimir Palant sorry for the late response, i would like to extract details from the Web Browser but precisely speaking i am a novice developer, anything that is good for a beginner will help

Comment: @Pratik: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#link-comment-reply, people you are replying to won't get notified otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Page Info dialog in Firefox already displays certificate information so it is a good idea to look at [how it is implemented](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/de483d897af4/browser/base/content/pageinfo/security.js). To sum up:

- The `<browser>` or `<tabbrowser>` element (`gBrowser` in a Firefox window) has a property [securityUI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#p-securityUI).
- The value of this property implements [nsISSLStatusProvider](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/de483d897af4/security/manager/boot/public/nsISSLStatusProvider.idl) interface which allows you to get to [nsISSLStatus](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/de483d897af4/security/manager/ssl/public/nsISSLStatus.idl).
- From there you can get to [nsIX509Cert](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/de483d897af4/security/manager/ssl/public/nsIX509Cert.idl) which has all the necessary information.

Code example:

```
var status = gBrowser.securityUI
                     .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISSLStatusProvider)
                     .SSLStatus;
if (status && !status.isUntrusted)
{
  // This shows: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority,O=Equifax,C=US
  alert(status.serverCert.issuerName);

  // This shows: Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
  alert(status.serverCert.issuerOrganizationUnit);
}
```

Note that the interface doesn't provide a way to extract issuer's country, you will have to parse `status.serverCert.issuerName` value yourself. Also, you only get the information on the immediate issuer this way, not the root CA. To get to the root CA you should use `status.serverCert.issuer` property and walk up the chain.

Comment: Actually i have one more idea, using **PHP script to call a bash script which executes OpenSSL** commands, the script will be provided with the _URL of the Web-Server_, can i have your opinion about the how feasible the solution is ?? Thanks for the prompt reply and nice solution

Comment: @PratikBosamiya: You are asking the wrong person. You probably want to create a new question with appropriate tags.

Comment: i am actually facing some problems in parsing **status.serverCert.issuerNaame**, can you tell if the value returned from the function can be stored as a String, if no can you suggest some ideas for parsing. I interpreted the value as String and used the `**lastIndexOf()**` function but the script didn't work, so please can you help me with it.

Comment: @PratikBosamiya: Again, asking a new question is probably a good idea. Personally I would split that string by commas and then parse each individual value.