# How to tell if a site is using SSL

Tags: security, ssl, xulrunner

I've developed a standalone XULRunner app which I'm using as a browser. I'm not displaying the URL in the app. But I'd like to tell if the site accessed is using SSL (i.e., the URL starts with `https://`). I'd like to display a message to the user if the section of the site they are in is secure or not. And, I guess the way to do it is by inspecting if a URL is using SSL or not. I've done some searches but no success so far, but I haven't given up. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

I've done some changes, and now my `onSecurityChange()` method is shown below.

```
onSecurityChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aState) { 
  if((aState & Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.STATE_IS_SECURE) == 0) {
    document.getElementById("lblConnectionStatus").setAttribute("value", "Insecure Connection");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("lblConnectionStatus").setAttribute("value", "Secure Connection");
  } 
  return 0;
```

}

However, it doesn't seem to change when I transition from insecure to secure pages. I've tried it with Yahoo and Hotmail, to see whether the problem is with the application I'm accessing, but there, too, it behaves the same.

Any pointer on what I may be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than that - even if the page itself is loaded via SSL it could embed scripts loaded via plain HTTP. That would mean that the entire page is *not* secure because the insecure script can compromise everything else. So you should rely on existing mechanisms, namely [`browser.securityUI` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser#p-securityUI) (also available on `tabbrowser`). The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8253991/785541) explains how one would check the SSL status of a page.

However, you probably want to learn when the SSL status changes. You would [use a progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) for that. The method `onSecurityChange()` will be called for all relevant changes, you will need to check the `aState` parameter (the connection is only secure when `aState & Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.STATE_IS_SECURE` gives you a non-zero value).

Comment: Thanks loads, Palant. Let me try it out.

Comment: Hello Palant. I've done some changes to incorporate your suggestions, but I'm facing some issues. I've updated the question (above) to reflect this. What do you think I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I'll troubleshoot this tonight. Will let you know my findings tomorrow.

Comment: I haven't succeeded in this. What I've done is, in addition to the code above (refer to question), I've used a regular expression to check the URL format; the `HTTPS` section of the URL. I know its a desperate move, but I don't think I have much in terms of options. I've learned a lot on XULRunner security because of you, Palant. As such, I'm accepting your answer.